# eventClick change background-color

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to change the "event" `background-color` when I click the event in `FullCalendar`

I am trying the following -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        editable: true,

        events: "json-events.php",

        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            alert(event.id);
        },

        loading: function(bool) {
            if (bool) $('#loading').show();
            else $('#loading').hide();
        },

        eventClick: function(event){
            $(event.target).css('background-color','yellow');
        }

    });

});
```

This however does nothing. Can this be done and can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `$(event).css('background-color', 'yellow')`?

Comment: You should check, which contents are passed to `event`. Maybe the element you tried to access is not available within this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
eventClick: function(event) {
    event.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    $('#mycalendar').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
},
```

Answer (score 1):

`eventClick` passes an FC [event object](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/), not a jQuery event. You can change the calendar event's properties, and then just [updateEvent](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/updateEvent/).

Answer (score 0):

Your function callback doesn't have the scope to use `$(this)` - that's why it's passed the jQuery Event object.

You should use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) - this is the DOM element which initiated the event.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot with so little info. How are you binding this event callback? Are you using `$(event.target)`?

Comment: I have added the code that initiates the calendar. Its pretty much stock from the documentation.

Comment: Right, so this isn't a jQuery event - http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/. Use `event.backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   eventClick: function(event){
        $(this).css('background-color','yellow');
    }
```

Comment: Please add documentation on your answer. Stackoverflow is not just a community to give answers but to teach questionnaires as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
eventClick: function(info) {
  info.el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.