# fullCalendar eventClick not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar in an app. I want to change cell background color by clicking on cell, but eventClick not fired.
Can anyone help me please.
here the code:

```js
 $(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();


            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            
                eventClick: function (event) {
                    
                    alert('hello');
                    event.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');

                },
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'agendaWeek'
                },
                editable: true,
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                slotMinutes:60
            });
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657414/eventclick-change-background-color) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797928/change-background-color-of-event-on-click-in-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dayClick event.

```
$(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth();
            var y = date.getFullYear();


            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                dayClick: function (date, jsEvent) { //Added this, use jsEvent for more customization
                     $(jsEvent.target).css('background-color', 'red');
                },
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'agendaWeek'
                },
                editable: true,  // Ensure you have this true
                disableResizing:true,   // Ensure you have this true
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                slotMinutes:60
            });
        });
```

at day click you can customize your css.

Comment: dayClick work for me but I need to change the color of the hour in day, and  not the all day

Comment: @natush I have updated my code, please check. This is working for me.

Comment: Now it is coloring an hour but of the whole week. It probably impossible. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the UpdateEvent:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       eventClick: function(event, element) {    
           event.title = "CLICKED!";    
           $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);    
       }
   });
```

SOURCE: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/updateEvent/

Comment: doesn't work in version 4 which is also what the above answer is linked to. Anyone got an answer for version 4 in a .Net environment?